# Return the amount of scrolling done on a page that does not have overflow in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a page that is fixed to be 100% the width and height of the viewport with overflow hidden. I would like to get the amount a user has 'scrolled' inside the view port so i can fire certain functions once a threshold is met. I understand that scroll isn't technically the correct terminology here as there is nothing to scroll through, i think it's more the case of, if the page was scrollable, how much would they have scrolled?

I know that this is possible to do using scrollTop and various other methods, however this requires the page to have an overflow. In this case, the scrollTop will always return 0 because the height of the body will always be 100% the height of the view port.

Does anyone know of any other ways to achieve this?

```css
body {
  background: #1f1f21;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'georgia';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>How much have you scrolled?</h1>
```

Comment: Could you create an example with the snippet function in the editor? So we can work on that.

Comment: Hey @ChrisR, there wouldn't really be anything to create. I't would just be a blank page with the body set to height: 100vh and overflow: hidden.

Comment: Does it have to be cross-platform or desktop only?

Comment: @ChrisR cross platform preferably

Comment: @chrisR i'm playing around with wheelDelta, which gives me 1 / -1 depending on scrolling up or down but doesnt give me a distance

Comment: Well, you won't have a distance as you did not scroll/move anything.

Comment: @ChrisR correct, which is why i am asking this question. Perhaps i should say how much the mouse wheel has been moved inside the document

Comment: If you're getting the wheel delta as 1 or -1 then just add that value to a global var that you initialise as 0.